# Structs in go and working with pointers

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I am trying my hand on my first go program which is supposed to be a very simple IRC bot.

I have the part of the connections etc done but I am confused with structs and pointers such. The structs are new to me coming from languages that use classes.

I have this struct and the constructor for it:

```
type Bot struct {
    server  string
    port    string
    nick    string
    channel string
    pass    string
    conn    net.Conn
}

// NewBot main config
func NewBot() *Bot {
    return &Bot{
        server:  "irc.twitch.tv",
        port:    "6667",
        nick:    "username",
        channel: "#channel",
        pass:    "password123",
        conn:    nil,
    }
}
```

My connect() method looks like this

```
func (bot *Bot) Connect() (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    ircbot := NewBot()
    conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", bot.server+":"+bot.port)
    // irc connection...
    return bot.conn, nil
}
```

Everything of that works fine the problem I am having is with another method to my struct named Message. It's just supposed to send a message. Looks like this:

```
// Message to send a message
func (bot *Bot) Message(message string) {
    if message == "" {
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Bot: " + message + "\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(bot.conn, "PRIVMSG "+bot.channel+" :"+message+"\r\n")
}
```

everytime when I then try to use this function I get this error and the program crashes

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x20 pc=0x463d73]
```

I'm unsure about how to use the & and * signs correctly to achieve what I want to do.

I thought a goroutine is something that is for multithreading and is done by saying "go [do something]" but I don't use that anywhere.

Edit:
**Solution**

Thanks I found the solution! For those interested: 
I created a new instance of Bot in the place where I called the Message() function which resulted in an empty conn.

This was the important bit, I stupidly didn't post here. handle() wasn't even a method of Bot which is even more stupid of me.

```
func handle(line string) {
    ircbot := NewBot();
    // get username, message etc...
    ircbot .CmdInterpreter(username[1], usermessage)
}
```

and this is the correct way:

```
func (bot *Bot) handle(line string) {
    // get username, message etc...
    bot.CmdInterpreter(username[1], usermessage)
}
```

Comment: _"everytime when I then try to use this function I get this error and the program crashes"_ You should probably include the calling code in your question.

Comment: Probably you are calling `Message` on a nil bot which is basically the same as calling a method on a null object e.g. in Java. So this has nothing to do with pointers, & and * but you forgot to properly build a bot before invoking methods on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here seems to be with the `Connect` method, and not really with pointers in particular:

```
func (bot *Bot) Connect() (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    ircbot := NewBot()
    conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", bot.server+":"+bot.port)
    // irc connection...
    return bot.conn, nil
}
```

The method is defined to be on (a pointer to the) Bot struct, but it  creates a new `Bot`, on this line:

```
ircbot := NewBot()
```

and then proceeds to use the one the method is defined on (called `bot`, not `ircbot`). If you choose to keep it so that there are separate `NewBot` and `Connect` functions (which is fine), then you should change it so that `Connect` actually uses an instantiated `*Bot`:

```
func (bot *Bot) Connect() (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", bot.server+":"+bot.port)
    // irc connection...
    return bot.conn, nil
}
```

and call it with something like this:

```
bot := NewBot()
conn, err := bot.Connect()
```

The error,

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

is probably because you are accessing `bot` in the `Connect` method (e.g. in `bot.server`) but it has not been defined, and the pointer is nil.

Comment: Couldn't the error be a result of `fmt.Fprintf(bot.conn` in `Message` on a `Bot` that he thought he had connected, but actually didn't because of how `Connect` is written?

Comment: I have removed newBot() from the connect function because it didn't make much sense to me to create a new instance there.  And the connection still works but the conn seems to be empty for when I call Message()

Comment: @Michael I'm speculating a bit with the error, but yeah, my best guess it's because something is being called on an uninstantiated bot. Could be `bot.conn`, as you said

Comment: I've updated my question with the solution. Thank you very much guys. Really fast and good help